# Citing in APA style with year in brackets

Tags: citing, apa-style

I'm writing my master thesis and citing in the APA style. Below is a picture how it looks right now:

[image: citation]

While it looks fine in general, I would like to alter the year and put it in brackets. Furthermore, erase the comma that comes after the author but leave the one that comes after the year so that it the final version looks like that:

Ruoff et al. (1953), p. 16

Because I copied the code to bring it to the near-final version I don't know how to alter it further to bring it to the wanted form.

The code that I have in the preamble looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ibid}{Ibid.}
  \let\@predcite\@empty
  \let\@currcite\@empty
\def\citef{\kernel@ifnextchar[\citef@{\citef@[]}}
\def\citef@[#1]{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\citef@@[{#1}]}{\citef@@[][{#1}]}}
\def\citef@@[#1][#2]#3{%
  \def\@currcite{#3}%
  \unskip
    \ifx\@currcite\@predcite
      \footnote{#1 \ifx\tempa\@empty\unskip\fi%
      \ibid\ifx\tempb\@empty\else\NAT@cmt #2\fi}%
    \else%
      \footnote{\citealp[#1][#2]{#3}}%
    \fi
  \gdef\@predcite{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Furthermore, I cite like this in the text (this is for the example shown in the picture above):

```
\citef[p. 16]{ruoff53}
```

In advance, thank you so much for your advice. Your help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

After Bernard's tips I have now the following code:

Can you give me further hints? I altered the body of my text to the following, bit it seems to be a complete mess...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{rotating}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ibid}{Ibid.}
  \let\@predcite\@empty
  \let\@currcite\@empty
\def\citef{\kernel@ifnextchar[\citef@{\citef@[]}}
\def\citef@[#1]{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\citef@@[{#1}]}{\citef@@[][{#1}]}}
\def\citef@@[#1][#2]#3{%
  \def\@currcite{#3}%
  \unskip
    \ifx\@currcite\@predcite
      \footnote{#1 \ifx\tempa\@empty\unskip\fi%
      \ibid\ifx\tempb\@empty\else\NAT@cmt #2\fi}%
    \else%
      \footnote{\citealp[#1][#2]{#3}}%
    \fi
  \gdef\@predcite{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}
\input{ma_chapters/introduction}
.
.
.
.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

Comment: It can easily be done with `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: OK, and if I change to that, can I still cite in footnote the same way as before? I'm kind of sceptic changing everything up again when 90% is working right now (apart from the problems stated above).

Comment: There is a `\footcite` command and a compatibility module, called with the `natbib` option. See §3.7.9 of biblatex's documentation for details. One of the advantages of biblatex is that it is easier to customise than a bibtex style.

Comment: Can you give me further hints? I altered the body of my text (see Edit in first post), but it seems to be a bit of a mess... :)

Comment: @Bernard - I believe the `biblatex-apa` package implements the citation callout and formatting requirements of the current `APA` manual, which (in BibTeX) is implemented via the `apacite` package and `apacite` bibliography style. The `apalike` bibliography style, which is what the OP appears to be using, is *much older* than the `apacite`package, and it doesn't correspond all that closely to current APA formatting guidelines.

Comment: @Madjens: I've posted a solution with `biblatex-apa`. I think your mess was due to mising `biblatex` and `natbib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're OK with the `apalike` bibliography style, the `natbib` citation management package, and BibTeX in general, you could create a new macro that implements your desired citation callout format.

```
\newcommand\mycite[2][]{\citeauthor{#2}\ (\citeyear{#2})\ifx#1\undefined\else, #1\fi}
```

If the first, optional argument isn't specified, nothing is printed after `\citeyear{#2}`; in effect, if no optional argument is provided, `\mycite` behaves like `\citet` would.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{ruoff,
  author = "A. Ruoff and B. Woof and C. Zoot",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 1953,
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\newcommand\mycite[2][]{%
  \citeauthor{#2}\ (\citeyear{#2})\ifx#1\undefined\else, #1\fi}
\begin{document}
\mycite[p.~16]{ruoff}  % with optional argument

\mycite{ruoff}  % without optional argument -- no comma is printed

\citet{ruoff}   % compare with output of "\citet"
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To place these citation callouts in a footnote, you could use a macro such as `\myfootcite`, defined as follows:

```
\newcommand\myfootcite[2][]{\footnote{\mycite[#1]{#2}.}}
```

If you don't want the period ("full stop") at the end of the footnote material, just omit the `.` after `{#2}`.

---

*Second addendum*, to accommodate the OP's request for a citation macro that prints out "Ibid." if the latest entry is the same as that from the preceding citation command:

Compared with the earlier solution, all that's required is to add a test if the current citation's key is the same as the one used in the previous citation. The following code provides two user macros: `\tcite`, for in-text citations, and `\fcite`, for in-footnote citations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[textheight=2in]{geometry} %% just for this example
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{ruoff,
  author = "A. Ruoff and B. Woof and C. Zoot",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 1953,
}
@article{abc,
  author = "Anna Andersen and Bertha Branson and Carla Carlsson",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",   
  year   = 2053,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\def\prevcite{} % initialize \prevcite
%% macro for in-text citation
\newcommand\tcite[2][]{%  
  \def\newcite{#2} 
  \ifx\prevcite\newcite 
    Ibid.%
  \else%
    \gdef\prevcite{#2}% update \prevcite
    \citeauthor{#2}\ (\citeyear{#2})%
  \fi
  \ifx#1\undefined\else, #1\fi}
%% macro for in-footnote citation
\newcommand\fcite[2][]{\footnote{\tcite[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}


bla bla\fcite{ruoff}

more bla bla\fcite[p.~75]{ruoff}

still more bla bla\fcite[p.~101]{abc}

further bla bla\fcite{abc}

final bla bla\fcite[p.~999]{abc}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! :) However, how do I cite like this in footnote? When I use \mycite it does the citation in the text, but I would rather have it in a footnote.

Comment: @MadJens - How do you currently generate citation callouts that show up in footnotes?

Comment: \citef[p. 16]{ruoff53} which generates the citation in the footnote thanks to the code quoted in the OP (\makatletter...\makeatother)

Comment: @MadJens - I've posted an addendum to suggest an additional macro called `\myfootcite`.

Comment: Immense, thank you!! A small last question: When I used the \citef command beofre, it used to automatically generate Ibid. citation in the footnote if the same reference was used successively. Is it possible to bring that back? It wouldn't be the end of the world if that wasn't possible anymore, but I'd prefer to have the option later on.

Comment: For my doctoral thesis, I use the apacite package. In the case you're talking about, I use the following bib entry and it works well : @book{Anzieu2003,
   author = {Anzieu, Didier and Doron, Jack and Houzel, Didier and Missenard, André and Enriquez, Micheline and Anzieu, Annie and Guillaumin, Jean and Lecourt, Édith and Nathan, Tobie},
   title = {Les enveloppes psychiques},
   publisher = {Dunod},
   address = {Paris, France, France},
   year = {2003},
}

Comment: @domi - Thanks for letting me know that these macros work with the `apacite` package (and `apacite` bibliography style too, right?) as well. In fact, they should work with any bibliography style that can generate authoryear-style callout. The only real requirement is that that the `natbib` package must be loaded, either directly or through a package option such as `natbibapa`.

Answer (score 4):

A way of doing things with `biblatex-apa`. You can emulate natbib commands with the `natbib` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{ruoff,
  author = "A. Ruoff and B. Woof and C. Zoot",
  title = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year = 1953,
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

%
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
 \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
% Multiple cites in one command
 {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
% \bibcloseparen%
% Single cite
 {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
% No author/editor
 {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
 \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}%
 {\nameyeardelim}%
 {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
 \bibcloseparen%
 \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
% Normal cite
 {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
 {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}%
 {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
 {\printnames{shortauthor}}
 {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}\addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
 \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}%
 {\nameyeardelim}%
 {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
 \bibcloseparen%
 \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
 \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\cite[p.~16]{ruoff} % with optional argument

\textcite{ruoff} % without optional argument -- no comma is printed

\citet{ruoff} % compare with output of "\citet"

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]